Ubuntu boots to tty with no network and no Desktop GUI
Ubuntu 20.04.
I was trying to upgrade python 3.8 and did a bunch of apt-get update/upgrade followed by commands to try to finally remove python.   While still in the Desktop GUI I noticed the terminal app was gone.  I rebooted and it only got to the tty.  No further apt-get commands work because networking is gone.   I tried to use nmtui as described in this post Ubuntu boots w/o gui on tty1 w/o network
but really don't know what to do once I've added an ethernet connection.   There are other input boxes that I might need to fill but don't know what to put for inputs.  The only way I had of accessing my router settings was via the browser on this machine so if I need IP addresses I don't know them.   I've burned ubuntu 22.04.4 to USB but the machine won't boot from it.  After I select run/try ubuntu it takes a few seconds to get to a Dell splash screen.  I see the USB flashing but it never gets further.   Any ideas of what I can try to restore the existing Ubuntu or get to the next one?

Never try to change the default version of python in Ubuntu. Now you will have to reinstall.

I've burned ubuntu 22.04.4 to USB but the machine won't boot from it. After I select run/try ubuntu it takes a few seconds to get to a Dell splash screen -- Perhaps the image got corrupted while downloading. Download again, verify checksums, and flash to USB drives once again.

Any ideas of what I can try to restore the existing Ubuntu - It is much easier to reinstall Ubuntu. 24.04 will be released tomorrow, you can install that. Moreover, if you need a different version of python, use anaconda. Don't try to modify the default python version.

I wasn't aware that 3.8 was the default version of Python on Ubuntu.   I've flashed 2 different USB drives with Ubuntu 22.04.4  times once using Etcher on a Mac, another using Linux Mint and got the same behavior from both

Please download Ubuntu once again, and try flashing that

I was able to solve my problem by not choosing the install or try ubuntu option.  I chose the one below it which then provided options for me to install ubuntu 22 and to preserve my ubuntu 20 system so I have no lost data.

In any case, if you need a different python version, use Anaconda. Don't try to change the python version shipped with ubuntu
